# SQL Query between two years to see distinct titles

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I need to query the table for the 
distinct # of titles where LOCAL_TITLE, SECONDARY_TITLE, and FORMAT_TITLE are in Year 2014, but not in Year 2013?

Table name: stage_data_all
columns: LOCAL_TITLE, SECONDARY_TITLE, FORMAT_TITLE and YR_DATA (two values, either 2013 or 2014)

I want to compare LOCAL_TITLE, SECONDARY_TITLE, FORMAT_TITLE against the year and find only values that are in 2014 but not in 2013.

Thank you.

SOLUTION 1:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT LOCAL_TITLE, SECONDARY_TITLE, FORMAT_TITLE
          FROM [STG].[dbo].[stage_data_all]
          WHERE YR_DATE = 2014) AS Y
          LEFT OUTER JOIN
          (SELECT LOCAL_TITLE, SECONDARY_TITLE, FORMAT_TITLE
          FROM [STG].[dbo].[stage_data_all]
          WHERE YR_DATE = 2013) AS X
          ON Y.LOCAL_TITLE = X.LOCAL_TITLE
          AND Y.SECONDARY_TITLE = X.SECONDARY_TITLE
          AND Y.FORMAT_TITLE = X.FORMAT_TITLE
    WHERE X.LOCAL_TITLE IS NULL
    X.SECONDARY_TITLE IS NULL
    X.FORMAT_TITLE IS NULL
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Please provide table structure, sample data and expected results

Comment: So my table has a column [YR_DATA] that has either 2013 or 2014. I want to see if my columns LOCAL_TITLE, SECONDARY_TITLE, and FORMAT_TITLE have different titles between these two years. I was thinking about doing a left outer join but I am not sure if its right.

Comment: Please post the table structure in your question. People aren't going to read all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it doesn't look like you have any ID's, try this:

```
select distinct
  LOCAL_TITLE
, SECONDARY_TITLE
, FORMAT_TITLE
from MyTable mt
left outer join (select distinct
                  LOCAL_TITLE
                , SECONDARY_TITLE
                , FORMAT_TITLE
                from MyTable
                where YR_DATA = '2013'
                )t
                    on t.LOCAL_TITLE = mt.LOCAL_TITLE
                    and t.SECONDARY_TITLE = mt.SECONDARY_TITLE
                    and t.FORMAT_TITLE = mt.FORMAT_TITLE
where (t.LOCAL_TITLE is NULL
and t.SECONDARY_TITLE is NULL
and t.FORMAT_TITLE is NULL)
and mt.YR_DATA = '2014'
;
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response. I appreciate it. I solved it. It's very similar to your answer. We're off just by placement of " and mt.YR_DATA = '2014' ".

Comment: Good to hear.  You should post your solution and chose it for the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct LOCAL_TITLE, SECONDARY_TITLE, FORMAT_TITLE from stage_data_all columns where YR_DATA != '2013' and YR_DATA = '2014'
```

I feel like I might be missing something because this seems relatively straight forward?

If you need the count of these records just wrap it in a select with a count:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct LOCAL_TITLE, SECONDARY_TITLE, FORMAT_TITLE from stage_data_all columns where YR_DATA != '2013' and YR_DATA = '2014')
```